# slow painting when setting the background color to be opaque

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabs, panel

making panel background color opaque causes slow painting of the controls in the panel.

I have .net 4 winforms app it uses tabs and on 2 of the tabs i load a background image. I overlay this with a panel with controls on it make them opaque by setting

```
 panel1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(200, Color.White);
```

If i comment out the line the panel and controls draw instantly, with the above line it takes a second to paint all the controls.

How can i have it paint faster but still be opaque?

Edit

I have added the following code but still have the same problem:

```
class DrawPanel : Panel
    {
        public DrawPanel()
        {
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a __DoubleBuffered__ subclass of Panel : `DrawPanel { public DrawPanel { DoubleBuffered = true;}}`

Comment: That's not an opaque color. It's 78% opacity (200/255). How many panels are you rendering this way?

Comment: @ theB 2 panels, one on per tab, 2 tabs.

Comment: @TaW I have added code as per my edit but it still is very slow! not sure if i did it right or not!

Comment: Well, did you also change the panel1 you use to be a DrawPanel?? You can do that by bravely editing the two spots in the Form1Designe.cs file whe it is declared (at the end) and created (at the top) from `Panel` to `DrawPanel`

Comment: You are using a partially transparent color.  Something the Panel class supports, however it needs to render the background pixels first before applying the BackColor brush.  It asks its Parent to paint those pixels.  That of course takes more time.  If the parent has a BackgroundImage then it can take a *lot* more time, the usual problem.  You must pay attention to the pixel format and the size of a background image to get decent rendering speeds.  Use 32bppPArgb, it is x10 times faster than all the other ones.  And be sure to resize the image yourself so it is an exact fit.

Comment: @TaW not sure what i need to change sorry...

Comment: @HansPassant this does seem to fit what is happening, I have manually sized the background image to be an exact match to the tab page. however i don't know to use 32bppPArgb to speed things up any examples of how to use it for a tab control?

Comment: Use the [Bitmap constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3567824/17034) that takes the PixelFormat argument.